# JS infinite scroll giving duplicates and overloading pokeAPI

Tags: javascript

Infinite scroll gives duplicates.

I am building a pokedex site using pokeAPI and i want to implement infinite-scroll with some animation at the end but there is a problem, all works fine early but when i scroll down a lot it gives me duplicates cards and loads more than 30 items, as i set.
This is my js file.
I know i should caching it. I'm still learning.
I would also like any advice on how to improve this code, thanks!

```
const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=30";



async function getPokemonList(url){
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let json = await response.json();
    if(json.next !== null){
        await createPokemons(json.results);

        //console.log(json.results);
        return json.next;
    }

}

async function createPokemons(param){
    
    for (let pokemon of param){
        
        const response = await fetch(pokemon.url);
        let json = await response.json();

        let frontImage = json.sprites.front_default;
        let pokemonName = pokemon.name;

        let divElement = document.createElement("div");
        divElement.classList.add("grid-container__pokemon");
        divElement.classList.add("grid-container__pokemon-withGender");

        let imgElement = document.createElement("img");
        imgElement.setAttribute("src", frontImage);
        imgElement.classList.add("grid-container__pokemon-image");


        let textElement = document.createElement("span");
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(pokemonName);
        textElement.classList.add("grid-container__pokemon-name");

        textElement.appendChild(textNode);
        divElement.appendChild(imgElement);
        divElement.appendChild(textElement);

        document.querySelector(".grid-container").appendChild(divElement);

    }
}

async function infiniteScroll(){
    let nextUrl = await getPokemonList(url);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", async ()=>{
        console.log("scrollY: " + window.scrollY);
        console.log("innerHeight: " + window.innerHeight);
        console.log("scrollHeight: " + document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
        if(window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight){
            nextUrl = await getPokemonList(nextUrl);

        }
    })
    
}

async function main(){
    await infiniteScroll();
    
}

main();
```